# Show that every bounded monotonic sequence is Cauchy using the monotonic convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta, cauchy-sequences

So the monotonic convergence theorem simply states that: $\{s_n\}$ is a monotonic sequence. Then
$\{s_n\}$ is convergent if and only if $\{s_n\}$ is bounded. by def this means $|s_n - L| < \epsilon$.

Furthermore it is true that

$s_1 < s_2 < ...< s_n < ... < s_m < ....< L$ because our sequence is monotonic and bounded, where $L$ is the limit and belong to $R$ and $n,m$ belong to the Natural Numbers and $n,m > n_0$ .

Then would the argument

$|s_n - s_m| < |s_n - L| < \epsilon$ (so the arbitrary distance from $s_n$ to $s_m$ is less than distance from $s_n$ to the limit is less than Epsilon)

then $|s_n - s_m| < \epsilon$ is also true, then by definition the question has been satisfied ?

Please excuse my English it is not my first language.

Comment: if $(s_n)$ is increasing bounded, $L=sup\{s_n,n\in \mathbb N\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $(s_n)$ increasing and bounded.

let $L=sup\{s_n,n\in\mathbb N\}$ and

$\epsilon>0$ given.

then

$\exists N\in \mathbb N \; \;$
$L-\epsilon<s_N\leq L$

but $(s_n)$ is increasing, thus

$\forall n>p>N \; $

$ L-\epsilon<s_N\leq s_p\leq s_n\leq L$.

finally

$\forall n>p>N \; \;\;|s_n-s_p|<\epsilon$

$(s_n)$ is then a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense.

Comment: @user294448 No point there?